# Is there any automated way to create an xml template from existing xml files?

Tags: xml, templates

I have a whole bunch of xml files generated off of captured data, the problem is that these xml files end up really large usually 50 MB+ and there are multiples of them! Is there any way to generate a template off of existing files and then extract the unique data that can be substituted into the template to recreate the original file when necessary?

Comment: Sorry, in order to clarify, I do not mean xsd

Answer (score 0):

By template, are you referring to an XSD (Xml Schema Definition) for the XML? If so, and if you're using Microsoft tools, the XSD command-line tool (part of Visual Studio) is probably what you want - it can generate an XSD from an XML sample file.